# How to calculate execution time using java or C#

Tags: java, c#, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to write a program to calculate the execution time. If I place two separate codes side by side in the editor, it will tell me which code will take less time. I have learned data structure and time complexity but I did not get any clue how to implement it in the above project using java or C#.
I could not find any link. Any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: The execution time depends on the the input, specific versions of software, and often some random factors (like the other processes running).

Comment: I think you are mixing "time _complexity_" and "_execution_ time". They are not the same. Just because two samples of code are both O(n), that does not mean they will execute equally long. Even worse: One sample of code may execute faster then the other depending on the size of the input. So, there wouldn't even be a general "A is faster than B".

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the solution you could use is timing how much time it would take to execute code.
In java:
Here is a link that will tell you how to time the exception: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/execution-elapsed-time/

In c#:
Here is a link:https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/how-to-calculate-code-execution-time-in-csharp

You could calculate the time of execution and then you can just compare the numbers.

Comment: What you describe would be a benchmark. What I read from the question is that OP wants to be able to _predict_ relative runtimes of competing code samples.

Comment: @Fildor: problem is that often there is not a clear winner. For example some quadratic sorting algorithms run linear on *sorted* input, whereas for *n log n* variants, it can sometimes take *n log n* even on sorted input. This is to some extent related to the *No free lunch theorem*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem

Comment: Correct. I was just pointing out that this answer may not be what OP is looking for - of which I doubt it is even feasable given the requirements described in the question. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Fildor: no, the problem is undecidable (since otherwise one could solve the *halting problem*), even if you would consider worst-case only. So although you can construct algorithms that for (simple) function would be able to do that, you can (fundamentally) not do this for an arbitrary function. Furthermore for more sophisticated, it often already takes years of research to find a reasonable bound in terms of time complexity, so no this is not possible.

Comment: I agree, @WillemVanOnsem.